# How to check a highest point of a mask in opencv python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to find a highest point of an object in a mask of bitwise. I researched and found this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67482247/finding-highest-point-in-a-bitwise-mask-in-opencv-python) i did exactly as the answer said but the results were just (0,0) which are wrong

| My Mask | Expected Result |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |
| My Original Image |  |
| [image] |  |

I am just trying in the same image as the question

Here is the code for that

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def line(im, pt1, pt2, color, thickness):
    im = cv2.line(im, pt1, pt2, color=color, thickness=thickness, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    return im

def empty(a):
    pass

path = 'images/m_1.jpg'

global img
img = cv2.imread(path)
img = cv2.resize(img, (640, 480))
org_img = img.copy()
copy_img = img.copy()

img_blur = cv2.blur(img,(5,5))
imgHSV = cv2.cvtColor(img_blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

h_min = 0
h_max = 179
s_min = 0
s_max = 255
v_min = 48
v_max = 166

lower = np.array([h_min, s_min, v_min])
upper = np.array([h_max, s_max, v_max])

mask = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, lower, upper)

global imgResult
imgResult = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=mask)
imgResult = cv2.resize(imgResult, (640, 480))

cont, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

c = max(cont, key=cv2.contourArea)
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

image = cv2.line(img, (int(w/2),y), (int(w/2),y+h), (0,0,255), 2)

global cropped_img
cropped_img = copy_img[y:y + h, x:x + w]

draw_img = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], img.shape[2]), dtype="uint8")
cv2.drawContours(draw_img,[c],-1,(255,255,255),thickness=-1)

img_bitwise = cv2.bitwise_and(org_img, draw_img)

margin = 90
draw_img = draw_img[margin:-margin]
imgResult = imgResult[margin:-margin]
img = img[margin:-margin]
img_bitwise = img_bitwise[margin:-margin]

print(draw_img.shape[:2])

has_white = print(np.any(draw_img, axis=1))
print(np.argmin(has_white))

result_i = np.argmin(has_white)
print(np.argmin(img_bitwise[result_i,:]))


cv2.imwrite('bit_img.png',img_bitwise)

cv2.imshow("Track Images", imgResult)
cv2.imshow("Result Images", img)
cv2.imshow("Cropped Image", cropped_img)
cv2.imshow("Draw Image", draw_img)
cv2.imshow("bit_img", img_bitwise)


k = cv2.waitKey(0)

if k == 27:  # wait for ESC key to exit
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
elif k == ord('s'):  # wait for 's' key to save and exit
    cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\Anush\PycharmProjects\WeldPoolAnalysis\resultImages\imgResult.png', img)
    cv2.imwrite(r'C:\Users\Anush\PycharmProjects\WeldPoolAnalysis\resultImages\imgCropped.png', cropped_img)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Output Of The Script

```
(300, 640)
[[False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]
 [False False False]]
0
0
```

Comment: Use `np.where(has_white)` to find the coordinates of white pixels, then `np.argmin` on the y's.

Comment: @QuangHoang can you explain it as a from of code

Comment: @QuangHoang my results are always zero why is it happening ? any idea ? it always shows 0

Comment: Perhaps you have a white pixel at y=0 somewhere? Try applying a noise filter (gaussian or median) or `cv2.morphologyEx` opening/closing to your b/w image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `has_white = print(np.any(draw_img, axis=1))` doesn't make much sense because what you store in `has_white` is the result of `print()`, which is `None`. Try changing:

```
has_white = print(np.any(draw_img, axis=1))
print(np.argmin(has_white))
```

to:

```
has_white = np.any(draw_img, axis=(1, 2))
print(np.argmax(has_white))
```

Now you are taking `np.any` over multiple axes, and `has_white` will contain a value for each row that is `True` if the row contains white or `False` otherwise.

The next line uses `np.argmax()` rather than `np.argmin()`. This means it finds the maximum of your array (your array only contains `True` and `False` so the max will be `True`) and returns the first index of a row that contains that max value. Since the array contains `True` where you have white, this will be first row containing white.

Therefore it will print the row of your highest point in `draw_img`. Since you have applied a margin, `draw_img` is smaller than your input, so you will need to account for that.

Now that you have the row, you can find the column.

```
row_index = np.argmax(has_white)
column = draw_img[row_index]
column_has_white = np.any(column, axis=1)
column_index = np.argmax(column_has_white)
```

One end of your line is `(row_index, column_index)` and the other is `(draw_img.shape[0], column_index)`.

Comment: still have the error. And posted the output of `np.any(draw_img, axis=1)`and the final output of the co-ordinate's

Comment: thanks for you answer. i updated the code as your answer said but now it says  `numpy.AxisError: axis 2 is out of bounds for array of dimension 2
` and when i changed the axis to just one it says (0,59).

Comment: I'm surprised, `draw_img` should have 3 dimensions. Can you change `print(draw_img.shape[:2])` to `print(draw_img.shape)` so we can see the full array shape?

Comment: there was a mistake from my side becuase i unknowingly created 2d mask instead of a 3d but now it works.And the result is 59,0 | how can i draw line with this co-ordinate because to draw line you need two co-ordinate

Comment: I've added how to find the two ends of the line. By the way, my code should only have printed the row `59`, not `59,0` so the zero is coming from something else.

Comment: Once this is working as you want, it would be helpful if you post the whole edited code in your question so the  before and after are both there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232234/discussion-between-adfadfasf-and-michaelcg8).

Comment: what if i want to find the center point of the mask and draw a line there (how can i do it ?